# has_any() or in() on dynamic fails if values passed could map to GUIDS

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Consider this query:

```
let set1=dynamic(["6ab1c993-c138-92ab-abac-49c4d4680812"]);
let set2=dynamic(["6ab1c993c13892ababac49c4d4680812@email.com"]);
let set3=dynamic(["6ab1c993-c138-92ab-abac"]);
let dummyData=datatable(Timestamp:datetime, DynamicData:dynamic) [
    datetime(2019-12-30 01:00:00), dynamic({"Id": "6ab1c993-c138-92ab-abac-49c4d4680812", "Email": "6ab1c993c13892ababac49c4d4680812@email.com"})
];
// query1: fails: Relop semantic error: 'has_any' has the following semantic error: SEM0024: The source expression is of type 'dynamic' and cannot be compared with numeric arguments.
dummyData | where DynamicData has_any (toscalar(set1));
//
// query2: succeeds
dummyData | where DynamicData has_any (toscalar(set2));
//
// query3: succeeds
dummyData | where DynamicData has_any (toscalar(set3));
// query4: fails
dummyData | where DynamicData.Id in (toscalar(set1));
```

The first query fails because it thinks the RHS is numeric.
The second and 3rd queries succeed. If the values are coming from data, a query succeeding today could fail on a compile error later.

Please note that in this case, in() or set_intersect() aren't options since DynamicData is a complex property bag. Even if this worked for in(), 'DynamicData has_any ()' is drastically faster than 'DynamicData.child1.child2 in ()'.

**Edit1**: this is failing on in() as well, and seems to occur whenever the values in the list could possibly map to GUIDs.
Title updated and another example added.

**Edit2**: found a workaround that doesn't degrade performance: wrap the LHS in a tostring, like 'dummyData | where tostring(DynamicData) has_any (toscalar(set1));'

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that doesn't degrade performance:
Wrap the LHS in a tostring.

```
dummyData | where tostring(DynamicData) has_any (toscalar(set1));
```